# Pulling specific data on top and restricting its limit in MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have following sql query which pulls data with the id 627 to top and then it displays data with other ids

```
$sql_query = "select * from listing ORDER BY case when listing.makaan_id='627' then 1 else 2 end, listing_id DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$limit}";
```

im using php pagination system to paginate the results where i set the pagination limit to 10. Now i want to show only 4 results on top with the id 627 and rest with other ids, so in a set of 10 results 4 would be from the id 627 and other 6 will be from other ids, do i have any solution for this without writing another separate sql statement?

Comment: Not possible without using a separate query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM listing 
 WHERE makaan_id = 627 
 ORDER BY listing_id DESC
 LIMIT 4
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
  FROM listing 
 WHERE makaan_id <> 627 
    OR makaan_id IS NULL
 ORDER BY listing_id DESC
 LIMIT {$start} - 4, {$limit} - 4
```